# Map a Windows network folder using IPv6

Tags: network-shares, file-sharing, ipv6, browsing

I need to map or browse a network folder. I can only use IPv6 in the browser / URL. Is this possible?

I am using two Windows 7 machines, one Vista PC, and one Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The machines have been assigned the following static IP addresses respectively:

```
2001::4%64
2001::5%64
2001::6%64
2001::7%64
```

The network is created on a separate virtual switch in ESXi4.0 server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lazy way - [`2001--5s64.ipv6-literal.net`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_UNC_path_names). That is, change all colons to dashes; change `%` to `s` (for "scope"), and append the Microsoft's special `.ipv6-literal.net` domain.

The smart way would be to set up proper hostnames for these machines. Windows already does NetBIOS name resolution, DNS would be even better. As fallback, there also is [`/etc/hosts`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx#EDAA) – although Windows calls it `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Add a line to it, such as:

```
2001::4   vm5.example.com
```

(Disadvantage: Cannot specify an address scope. But your example addresses are global anyway, so shouldn't need one...)

Comment: Thanks it is working. Need to make sure that ipv6 on both pcs. and I need to make the environment to be working with ipv6 so i need to look for this lazy way. thanks. :)

Comment: NetBIOS name resolution isn't implemented on Windows for IPV6. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#Name_service) (crap source, I know)

Comment: Doesn't actually matter, as Windows has alternatives such as LLMNR (better than NetBIOS anyway).

Answer (score 11):

Follow these steps when specifying a literal IPv6 address in a UNC path:

1. Replace any colon (`:`) characters with a dash (`-`) character.
2. Append the text `.ipv6-literal.net` to the IP address.

e.g.

```
net use x: \\fe80-0-0-0-a0b6-99c9-2f6c-5759.ipv6-literal.net\admin$
```

or in the map drive dialog:

```
\\fe80-0-0-0-a0b6-99c9-2f6c-5759.ipv6-literal.net\admin$
```

Comment: Hi I tried these following steps. But not able to map or browse through.. :(. Is it working for you>?

Comment: It is working. Only thing is we need to make sure that we have setup the network properly, with gateway, subnet, and dns etc should be same in the entire network. Then it will work. Make sure both sides IPv6 enabled & ipv6 ping happening.
Thanks.